# New Java coder. Need help putting game into methods and classes

Tags: java, class, methods

So I want to put this game into classes & methods. So different pages with classes and leave the main method on one page. I have no idea how to do that, and I made this whole game by myself. If someone can help me it will be much appreciated. Basically I need help making a class design and inheritance (parent-child classes). Also method blocks such as gameStart().

Here is my game:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random; 


public class DungeonGame {

public static void main (String[] args){

    // System Objects
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random(); 

    // Game Variables
    String[] enemies = {"Skeleton", "Zombie", "Warrior", "Assassin"}; 
    int maxEnemyHealth = 75; 
    int enemyAttackDamage = 25; 


    // Player Variables
    int health = 100;       // How much health we have
    int attackDamage = 50;  // How much damage our player can do
    int numHealthPotions = 3;  // Number of health pots our player is set with
    int healthPotionHealAmount = 30; // Amount a health the pot will raise
    int healthPotionDropChance = 50; // Percentage drop

    boolean running = true; 

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Dungeon Game!"); //Welcome Message



    GAME: 
    while (running) {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

        int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth); // Get a random health for enemy (How strong is the enemy?)
        String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)]; //Set random enemy from array
        System.out.println("\t#" + enemy + " appeared! #\n");
        //           # Skelenton has appeared (example)

        while(enemyHealth > 0) {

            System.out.println("\tYour HP: " + health);
            System.out.println("\t+" + enemy + "'s HP: " + enemyHealth);
            System.out.println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("\t1. Attack");
            System.out.println("\t2. Drink health potion");
            System.out.println("\t3. Run!");

            String input = in.nextLine(); 
            if(input.equals("1")){
                int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
                int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDamage);


                enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                health -= damageTaken;

                System.out.println("\t> You strike the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage."); 
                System.out.println("\t> You receive " + damageTaken + " in retaliation!"); 

                if(health < 1) {

                    System.out.println(">t You have taken too much damage, you are to weak to go on!");
                    break; 
                }


            }

            else if (input.equals("2")){
                if(numHealthPotions > 0) {

                    health += healthPotionHealAmount;
                    numHealthPotions--;
                    System.out.println("\t> You drink a health potion, healing yourself for " + healthPotionHealAmount + "."
                                        + "\n\t> You now have" + health + "HP."
                                        + "\n\t> You have" + numHealthPotions + "health potions left.\n"); 

                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("\t> You have no health potions left!! Defeat enemies for a chance to get one. \n"); 
                    }

                }


           else if(input.equals("3")){
               System.out.println("\tYou run away from the " + enemy + "!");
               continue GAME; 




            }

            else {

                System.out.println("\tInvalid Command!");

            }

        }

        if(health < 1) {

            System.out.println("You limp out of the dungeon, weak from battle.");
            break; 
        }


        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(" # " + enemy + " was defeated! #"); 
        System.out.println(" # You have " + health + " HP left. #");
        if(rand.nextInt(100) < healthPotionDropChance) {

            numHealthPotions++;
            System.out.println(" # The " + enemy + " dropped a health potion! #");
            System.out.println(" # You now have " + numHealthPotions + "health potion(s). # ");




        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do now?");
        System.out.println("1. Continue fighting");
        System.out.println("2. Exit game");

        String input = in.nextLine();

        while(!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("invalid Command!");
            input = in.nextLine(); 
        }

        if(input.equals("1")) {

            System.out.println("You continue on your adventure!");
        }

        else if (input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("You exit the dungeon, successful from your adventures!"); 
            break;
        }



    }

        System.out.println("###############################");
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
        System.out.println("###############################");



}
```

}

Comment: So you don't have any exprerience with object oriented programming, is that right?

Comment: I'm really new. I can write basic code all in one page but it's hard for me to do it this way. My first month of coding. If you could help me put it in a class design and inheritance method and help me make method blocks I will really appreciate it it.

Comment: I'll post an answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Also, you didn't mention any *problem* with your code, which makes this an off-topic question.

Comment: Thank you Keiwan. You are so helpful. And Idos I am sorry? I wasn't sure where to post it then I just wanted help and learn. It's only my first month doing Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would divide your game into several classes based on the idea of OOP (object oriented programming). You should have classes for every entity of your game. I divided it into the Classes:

- DungeonGame (which holds the main function and acts as the main Game controller)
- Player
- Enemy
- GameCharacter (abstract)

The GameCharacter class is a parent class for the Player and the Enemy objects, since they share attribute and methods (such as health, attackDamage, attack(), takeDamage()...)

The DungeonGame class has the main game loop which is mostly the same as what you had written. The only changes are the points at which you wanted the player and/or the enemy to take some action. Now, instead of adjusting all of the variables directly in the loop, you call the respective functions on the Player and Enemy Object - such as attack(), takeDamage() -
and the Objects adjust their own variables.

This is the basic idea of Object Oriented Programming. Also note for example that only the Player and Enemy Objects know their own current health, so every time the gameController wants to print the player health, it has to "ask" for it by calling a getter function. You could also put the printing of the health into the Player class, if the print message was always the same...

This is just an example of how you could go about the structure of your game - you can still change lots of things to your liking. As another example, you could turn the Enemy class itself into another abstract class and create a class for each type of enemy. That way you could assign special powers to each individual enemy type.

DungeonGame.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random; 

public class DungeonGame {

Random rand;
Scanner in; 

Player player;
private int healthPotionDropChance;
boolean running;

public static void main (String[] args){

    DungeonGame game = new DungeonGame();
    game.run();
    System.out.println("###############################");
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
    System.out.println("###############################");

}

public DungeonGame(){
    // System Objects
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    rand = new Random(); 

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Dungeon Game!"); //Welcome Message

    player = new Player();
    healthPotionDropChance = 50;

}

public void run(){
    running = true;
    GAME:
    while (running) {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

        /*int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth); // Get a random health for enemy (How strong is the enemy?)
        String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)]; //Set random enemy from array
        System.out.println("\t#" + enemy + " appeared! #\n");
        //           # Skelenton has appeared (example)
        */
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy();
        String enemyType = enemy.getType();
        System.out.println("\t#" + enemyType + " appeared! #\n");

        while(enemy.getHealth() > 0) {

            System.out.println("\tYour HP: " + player.getHealth());
            System.out.println("\t+" + enemyType + "'s HP: " + enemy.getHealth());
            System.out.println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("\t1. Attack");
            System.out.println("\t2. Drink health potion");
            System.out.println("\t3. Run!");

            String input = in.nextLine(); 
            if(input.equals("1")){

                int damageTaken = enemy.attack();
                int damageProduced = player.attack();

                enemy.takeDamage(damageProduced);
                player.takeDamage(damageTaken);

                System.out.println("\t> You strike the " + enemyType + " for " + damageProduced + " damage."); 
                System.out.println("\t> You receive " + damageTaken + " in retaliation!"); 

                if(player.getHealth() < 1) {

                    System.out.println(">t You have taken too much damage, you are to weak to go on!");
                    break; 
                }


            }

            else if (input.equals("2")){
                if(player.getNumHealthPotions() > 0) {

                    player.applyPotion();
                    System.out.println("\t> You drink a health potion, healing yourself for " + player.getHealthPotionHealAmount() + "."
                                        + "\n\t> You now have" + player.getHealth() + "HP."
                                        + "\n\t> You have" + player.getNumHealthPotions() + "health potions left.\n"); 

                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("\t> You have no health potions left!! Defeat enemies for a chance to get one. \n"); 
                    }

                }


           else if(input.equals("3")){
               System.out.println("\tYou run away from the " + enemyType + "!");
               continue GAME; 




            }

            else {

                System.out.println("\tInvalid Command!");

            }

        }

        if(player.getHealth() < 1) {

            System.out.println("You limp out of the dungeon, weak from battle.");
            break; 
        }


        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(" # " + enemyType + " was defeated! #"); 
        System.out.println(" # You have " + player.getHealth() + " HP left. #");
        if(rand.nextInt(100) < healthPotionDropChance) {

            player.pickUpHealthPotion();
            System.out.println(" # The " + enemyType + " dropped a health potion! #");
            System.out.println(" # You now have " + player.getNumHealthPotions() + "health potion(s). # ");


        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do now?");
        System.out.println("1. Continue fighting");
        System.out.println("2. Exit game");

        String input = in.nextLine();

        while(!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("invalid Command!");
            input = in.nextLine(); 
        }

        if(input.equals("1")) {

            System.out.println("You continue on your adventure!");
        }

        else if (input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("You exit the dungeon, successful from your adventures!"); 
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Player.java:

```
public class Player extends GameCharacter {

private int numHealthPotions;   // Number of health pots our player is set with
private int healthPotionHealAmount;  // Amount a health the pot will raise
private int healthPotionDropChance;

public Player(){
    super(100,50);
    numHealthPotions = 3;
    healthPotionHealAmount = 30; 
}

public void applyPotion(){
    health += healthPotionHealAmount;
    numHealthPotions--;
}

public void pickUpHealthPotion(){
    numHealthPotions++;
}

public int getNumHealthPotions(){
    return numHealthPotions;
}

public int getHealthPotionHealAmount(){
    return healthPotionHealAmount;
}
}
```

Enemy.java:

```
public class Enemy extends GameCharacter{

private String[] enemies = {"Skeleton", "Zombie", "Warrior", "Assassin"}; 
private String type;
private int maxHealth; 
private int health;
private int attackDamage; 

public Enemy(){
    //generates a random enemy
    super(100,25);
    maxHealth = 75;
    attackDamage = 25;
    type = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)]; //Set random enemy from array
    health = rand.nextInt(maxHealth);

}

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

}
```

GameCharacter.java:

```
import java.util.Random; 

public abstract class GameCharacter {

Random rand;

int health;
int attackDamage;

public GameCharacter(int health, int attackDamage){
    rand = new Random();
    this.health = health;
    this.attackDamage = attackDamage;
}

public int attack(){
    return rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
}

public void takeDamage(int damage){
    health -= damage;
}

public int getHealth(){
    return health;
}

public void setHealth(int health){
    this.health = health;
}

public int getDamage(){
    return attackDamage;
}
}
```